# Username/password authentication curl attempt failture

Tags: authentication, curl

I'm trying to get an access token using following curl:

```
 curl --data grant_type=password&client_id=Y&client_secret=Z&username=A&password=B+C 
 https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

where Y = Consumer Key, Z = secret, A = username and B = password and C = security token.

I get the following error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}
```

I followed the instructions at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm. If anyone can tell me what I've done wrong, it would be brilliant. I've no clue why im getting this error.

Comment: Are you making a POST request here? I am not sure how to make a POST request in curl, but if you are not doing it now, please check that and try.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy    (from the curl man page)    -d, --data <data>
              (HTTP)  Sends  the  specified data in a POST request to the HTTP
              server, in the same way that a browser  does  when  a  user  has
              filled  in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will
              cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type
              application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Compare to -F, --form.

Comment: @jones this is working for me by the way. (I put the data in single quotes, but otherwise it's the same as what you have in your question)

Comment: Thanks @martin for the clarification. I use chrome POSTMAN app for testing my services where we set the HTTP method explicitly, hence got the doubt.

Comment: @martin hmm, could it be because i'm using http://onlinecurl.com/? usually i can perform curl requests using this site

Comment: @martin can you post your curl? if i put single quotes '' around the data, i get {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}

Comment: `curl --data 'grant_type=password&client_id=3&client_secret=1&username=m&password=3' https://analysis-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`

Comment: does it work with https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/to‌​ken as the url?

Comment: Yes, that works for me as well.

Comment: For some reason it worked using a different CURL website, I wasn't aware it could be website specific. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Interesting. Good to hear you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the login issue salesforce reported as fixed, however at least on the instance I'm on this issue is still ongoing for logins through the API.

From the report on [status.salesforce.com](https://status.salesforce.com), that you can find below, using the instance url `https://<yourinstance>.salesforce.com` instead of `https://login.salesforce.com` should fix the problem.

> **Salesforce login error issue**
>   May 17th 2017, 8:42 am
>   On May 17, 2017, The Salesforce Technology Team mitigated an intermittent login issue affecting a subset of customers. The issue began at 03:45 UTC and was resolved as of 05:47 UTC. Some customers may have experienced an intermittent error when attempting to login to test.salesforce.com or login.salesforce.com instead of directly to their instance. Thank you for your continued business and patience during this situation.

Comment: "using the instance url should fix the problem"? how do I obtain a instance url for my instance? I'm trying to access the api to get data to display on a website, no user login interaction

Comment: The data is hosted on a specific instance, so logging in via the browser (using any user of the same organization) redirects you to your instance. From the URL in the browser you can obtain the instance to use.

Comment: Using  https://eu2.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token gives the same error